# ptrdiff_t too small?

Tags: c++, c, d

I've always wondered: isn't `ptrdiff_t` supposed to be able to hold the difference of any two pointers *by definition*? How come it fails when the two pointers are too far? (I'm not pointing at any particular language... I'm referring to all languages which have this type.)

(e.g. subtract the pointer with address `1` from the byte pointer with address `0xFFFFFFFF` when you have 32-bit pointers, and it overflows the sign bit...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, it is not.

> **$5.7 [expr.add]** (from n3225 - C++0x FCD)
>   When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std::ptrdiff_t` in the `<cstddef>` header (18.2). As with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.
>   In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i − j` provided the value fits in an object of type `std::ptrdiff_t`. Moreover, if the expression `P` points either to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an array object, and the expression `Q` points to the last element of the same array object, the expression `((Q)+1)-(P)` has the same value as `((Q)-(P))+1` and as `-((P)-((Q)+1))`, and has the value zero if the expression `P` points one past the last element of the array object, even though the expression `(Q)+1` does not point to an element of the array object. Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

Note the number of times `undefined` appears in the paragraph. Also note that you can only subtract pointers if they point within the same object.

Comment: +1 Wow, I (obviously) never knew this undefined-ness was part of the standard. But, in this case, isn't `ptrdiff_t` just a glorified `signed size_t`?

Comment: @templatetypedef: I am glad, for once, not to wake up after the battle has been fought :) @Mehrdad: I would say it is :) On the other hand, nothing forbids the standard library implementation you use to use a 64-bits integer even on a 32-bits platform. The standard only says it's not mandatory for them to make the effort. The rest is Quality of Implementation issue.

Comment: @Matthieu: *Very* interesting, thanks for the great answer. (Haha I accepted the answer at zero seconds past the 10 minutes...)

Comment: In principle `ptrdiff_t` could be larger than `size_t` if your implementation allows arrays with more than `SIZE_MAX/2` elements. In practice this would be rather silly. Of course one should note that implementations where `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` are the same size are **buggy** (perhaps dangerously so) if they allow arguments greater than `SIZE_MAX/2` to `malloc` and successfully allocate blocks that large.

Comment: @R.: Thinking about it a bit more, it reminds me of the [binary search bug](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)...

Comment: "...within the same structure".  It's more "...within the same object".

Comment: @Mehrdad: Note that the "binary search bug" is not a bug in real world situations: because no array can be bigger than `SIZE_MAX/2`, the sum of two (unsigned) indices cannot wrap. The actual bug in the article you linked is using a signed index where an unsigned index is called for. Of course you're forced to do this in broken languages like Java that lack unsigned types...

Comment: @R.: You're missing a fact: No one says the binary search has to be on an *array*! (You could easily be binary-searching a file on the disk.) Furthermore, it's perfectly real-world because someone obviously found the bug in a real-world situation.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The same thing applies on disk. `off_t` is a signed type, so if you're searching in files, use the corresponding unsigned type (or larger) as your index. The article's claim is that almost every binary search or merge sort ever written is subject to this bug, and that's blatantly false. Incidentally, every binary search I've ever written uses index-of-first and count rather than index-of-first and index-of-last, at every step of the search, because it's easier that way...

Comment: @R.: Use an unsigned type? And what if I need to return the position it should be inserted in? If `off_t` is unsigned 32-bit, and the position is `0xF0000000`, then I can't return `~0xF0000000`... of course there's ways around it, but the point is that peopled don't think twice about it.

Comment: Position cannot be `0xF0000000`. `off_t` is a signed type. The highest position is then `0x7FFFFFFF` and adding two positions cannot overflow if you use an unsigned type.

Comment: Note that on most system (I.e. 2's complement ints) even with the overflow things will work as expected (despite being undefined) as long as you never need to check the sign.

Comment: @BCS: even with 2's complement ints (don't know any other, actually), there is still the risk that a particular CPU would generate a hardware trap on overflow/underflow for signed types.

Answer (score 8):

No, because there is no such thing as the difference between "any two pointers". You can only subtract pointers to elements of the same array (or the pointer to the location just past the end of an array).

Comment: But what if you *have* a really large array (perhaps because you *are* the kernel)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The kernel is allowed to make many unportable assumptions.  For example, Linux kernel code assumes that it will be compiled with GCC and that "long" is the same width as a pointer.  On both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, the difference between any two addresses will fit in 64 bits (because some of the high bits in a 64 bit address are unused).

Comment: Wait, what?! They assume `long` is the size of a pointer?? o__o
Why don't they just use `ptrdiff_t` (which I'd say is a safer bet) or create a custom typedef instead?

Comment: It's Linux, of course. There was a lot of conventional wisdom ignored during its early years. Just ask Tannenbaum.

Comment: The whole type system in Linux (the kernel) is a mess. Thankfully unless you do kernel development or have to deal with porting the kernel headers to be usable from user-space, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mehrdad: There are two types of processors Linux runs on, 32-bit ones where both pointers and `long` are 32 bits, and 64-bit ones where both pointers and `long` are 64 bits (`int` is always 32 bits). So yes, on the Linux kernel `long` is always the same size as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

To add a more explicit standard quote, `ISO 9899:1999 §J.2/1` states:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> [...]
>
> -- The result of subtracting two pointers is not representable in an object of type
> ptrdiff_t (6.5.6).

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely acceptable for `ptrdiff_t` to be the same size as pointer types, provided the overflow semantics are defined by the compiler so that any difference is still representable. There is no guarantee that a negative ptrdiff_t means that the second pointer lives at a lower address in memory than the first, or that ptrdiff_t is signed at all.

Comment: Hm... are you sure about the "or that ptrdiff_t is signed at all" part?

Comment: Not entirely, but I don't have my copy of the standard at hand, and I would not rely on this for anything (i.e. I'd use `a < b` rather than `a - b < 0` to compare pointers if I ever needed an ordering.

Comment: @Simon: Ah okay, +1 anyway, nice answer. :)

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is a signed type. There *is* a guarantee that negative difference `a-b` means `a` is at a lower index in the array than `b`, assuming the difference was defined to begin with.

Comment: Hm, a quick test with an array of size 0x90000000 shows that the g++ will rather complain about the size of the array than allow ptrdiff_t to overflow.

Comment: gcc complains about the array size, but a more troublesome issue is whether or not `malloc` and family forbid sizes greater than `SIZE_MAX/2`.

Comment: It is usually a lot less than that. Address space layout randomization will make that number different each time, but I'd assume you cannot allocate more than 1GB of contiguous memory on ia32.

Comment: @R..: If sizeof(int) is 4, and size_t is 32 bits, can a compiler legitimately allow the creation of objects larger than 2GB without making ptr_t 64 bits?  If not, what purpose would ptr_t serve?

Comment: @supercat: The C standard allows the compiler to do so, but the result of taking the difference would be undefined behavior (since it overflows) and there's no way to test before performing the difference whether it overflows, so there's no way to avoid the problem without ensuring that you never create objects larger than the max value that fits in `ptrdiff_t`. IMO this is a quality-of-implementation issue. Compilers and standard library implementations *should not* allow the creation of such objects.

Comment: @R..: I suppose from a standards perspective, there may in many environments a value N for which adding the declaration `int memoryGobbler[N];` at global scope could cause a program to enter the realm of Undefined Behavior without any diagnostic (historically, it was common for heap and stack to be allocated from opposite ends of a common pool containing everything that wasn't program code or static-duration data, so having just the right amount of static data could leave enough stack for a program to start, but not enough to do anything useful).

Comment: @R..: Thinking about it, I find myself amazed that there's been no discernible effort to standardize a "new C" language which whose defined behaviors would match those of "old C" for code which compiles on both, and where old code which didn't compile under new rules could generally be made to do so fairly easily, but where code which compiled under the new rules (without use of "use old rules" directives) would be far less prone to implementation-dependent or Undefined Behavior.  If there's a construct where different compilers presently do different things...

Comment: ...the ANSI committee seems to be inclined to have them keep doing so, often without providing any clean consistent way to achieve desired semantics.  To be sure, a compiler which rejects any program that might cause Undefined Behavior would be unable to compile some programs that would otherwise in reality run just fine.  Nonetheless, I don't know that the standard actually imposes any requirements upon programs whose static memory requirements exceed the specifications for a minimum implementation.  Why is that not a major defect?

Answer (score -2):

Over/underflow is mathematically well-defined for fixed-size integer arithmetic:

```
(1 - 0xFFFFFFFF) % (1<<32) =
(1 + -0xFFFFFFFF) % (1<<32) =
1 + (-0xFFFFFFFF % (1<<32)) = 2
```

This *is* the correct result!

Specifically, the result after over/underflow is an alias of the correct integer. In fact, every non-representable integer is aliased (undistinguishable) with one representable integer — count to infinity in fixed-size integers, and you will repeat yourself, round and round like a dial of an analog clock.

An N-bit integer represents any real integer modulo 2^N. In C, modulo 2^N is written as %(1<<32).

I believe C guarrantees mathematical correctness of over/underflow, but only for unsigned integers. Signed under/overflow is assumed to never happen (for the sake of optimization).

In practice, signed integers are two's complement, which makes no difference in addition or subtraction, so correct under/overflow behavior is guarranteed for signed integers too (although not by C).

Comment: *"In practice, signed integers are two's complement, which makes no difference in addition or subtraction"*... that makes no sense. Undefined is undefined -- *anything* could happen. Which means you can't rely on anything particular happening.

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. Most of the time The computation will be performed as stated but the compiler could also do whatever it wants: This is undefined behavior. [See this](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).