# ptrdiff_t: necessary to cast pointers when subtracting?

Tags: pointers

This line:

```
   if ((next_parse_point - current_parse_point) > p_chars_per_line)
```

produces the following warning:

```
 warning: possible ptrdiff_t overflow
```

To fix it, I've done the following:

```
   if (((ptrdiff_t)next_parse_point - (ptrdiff_t)current_parse_point) > p_chars_per_line)
```

I thought I'd be able to simply cast the returned result of the subtraction to `ptrdiff_t`, rather than having to cast each of the arguments, like:

```
   if ((ptrdiff_t)(p1-p2) > charsPerLine ) ...
```

but the same warning occurs.

Can someone provide an exaplanation, or a pointer to what I am missing?

Comment: What are the types of the two pointers?

Comment: The 'point' vars are all declared as char*.  This will need to compile and be lint-free on both 32- and 64-bit Unix.

Comment: I think the answer to this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860086/ptrdiff-t-too-small - but casting the pointers to ptrdiff_t before they're a difference feels like a really bad idea.

Comment: I agree that the casts as they are not are bad, and I'll change that (thank you), but I don't know what to change it to.  What would be the correct cast syntax to rid us of that warning?  BTW, I also found this article helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108605/which-type-should-i-use-for-a-pointer-ptrdiff-t-or-void

Comment: I don't have a compiler here which generates that warning, but I expect you can cast the pointers to integers and subtract those, as long as you take proper account of the size of your char type.  A cleaner solution would probably be `if((current_parse_point + pchars_per_line) > next_parse_point)` which avoids the whole pointer-subtraction horror altogether.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but won't it change the pointer math if I cast the char pointers to instead be integer pointers, because of the different sizes of the types?  Also, because I'm converting existing code from 32- to 64-bit, I don't have the liberty to make what corporate may consider "logic changes", as per your other suggestion :-)

Comment: The person who wrote a rule that says you're allowed to add a cast to a pointer involved in arithmetic but not to make 'logic changes' is unqualified for their role.  /Any/ cast you make to those pointers has the possibility of changing the arithmetic.  I didn't say cast to integer /pointers/, I said cast to integers, and then deal with the char size issue yourself - but I think that's a horrible solution.  Adding casts all over the place to remove lint when there's no test coverage is a recipe for disaster, and I hope it doesn't all blow up on you. Good luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation here is roughly as follows:

1. Your compiler has a ptrdiff_t that is a signed type that's no bigger than the size of a pointer on your platform.
2. One cannot guarantee to be able to store the difference of any two unsigned values in a signed type of the same length.
3. Because your two pointers are to single-byte values, the result of subtracting one pointer from another potentially falls foul of point 2 above.
4. The compiler warns you about this hazard.

It's easy to see this happening with 8-bit values - if A = 150 and B = 10, then the result of the subtraction would be 140 in an unsigned 8-bit value, which is -116 in a signed value - clearly that's a hazard if you then feed the value into a compare.  In real life, it would only be a hazard if your two pointers were more than half your address space apart, which is not completely unlikely in a 32 bit environment nowadays.

My suggestions are either:

- Rewrite the expression to avoid the subtract: `if((current_parse_point + pchars_per_line) > next_parse_point))`

or

- Pragma the warning off around that expression

or

- Cast the pointers from pointers into unsigned integers, so that the compiler thinks you 
  know what you're doing and doesn't warn you.  (IMO this is worse than a pragma, but it sounds like your work environment might be happier with this)

Comment: Thank you, Will.  I'm in full agreement that I'm working for upper management who believe globals are the solution to everything ;-)  Your explanation is concise and exactly what I need to present to said management.  Thanks again.